# React and Bulma: How to make column vertically scrollable using css?

Tags: css, reactjs, bulma

Using React and Bulma [columns](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/), how do you make a column vertically scrollable (overflow-y) using css?

In the code provided below, I am just fetching a bunch of filters that are displayed in the first column thanks to the *Filters* component. Then I want to display a list of documents using the *DocumentListView* component. This is happening in the second column.

Note that I added a *scrollable* class to the second column in order to make this column vertically scrollable.

```
import React from 'react'
import Filters from './components/Filters/Filters'
import DocumentListView from './components/DocumentListView/DocumentListView'
import { fetchFilters } from './_actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import './App.css'


class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchFilters()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className='App'>
                    <div className='columns'>
                        <div className='column is-one-fifth'>
                            <Filters />
                        </div>
                        <div className='column scrollable'>
                            {/* This column should be vertically scrollable */}
                            <DocumentListView />
                        </div>
                        <div className='column'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchFilters: () => dispatch(fetchFilters()),
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Here is the App.css file I am using:

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.App {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2%;
}

.columns {
    height: 100%;
}

.scrollable {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add max-height to columns class. like this:-

```
.columns{
max-height: 200px;
}
```

if you want your centre div's height to be dependent on its sibling the do this:-

```
.scrollable{
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}

.scrollable>div{
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   overflow-y: auto
}
```

I hope it'll work

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to change max-height to 650px so that the second column use almost all vertical space. Why is it that I can't set columns' max-height to 100% ?

Comment: max-height 100% is the of the content which the div holds. Which means the max-height is equal to the height of the div